# How do I replace special characters in a URL?

Tags: c#, url, encoding

This is probably very simple, but I simply cannot find the answer myself :(

Basicaly, what I want is, given this string:

"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c# objects"

I want this output:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c%23+objects

I'm sure there's some helper class somewhere buried in the Framework that takes care of that for me, but I'm having trouble finding it.

EDIT: I should add, that this is for a Winforms App.

Comment: Something seems off here.  Where are you getting a URL without your query values being escaped?  If you are constructing the URL yourself, you should be escaping the query values ("en" and "c# objects"), **then** concatenating them into the URL.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(string)

Should sort out any troublesome characters

To use it you'll need to add a reference to System.Web (Project Explorer > References > Add reference > System.Web)

Once you've done that you can use it to encode any items you wish to add to the querystring:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("c# objects");
```

Comment: Dang 58 seconds too slow, time to breakout Mavis Beacon! ;-)

Comment: Hmm didn't know about this one. :)

Comment: Can you just add a reference to System.Web (Project Explorer > references > Add reference > System.Web), and use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("c# objects");

Comment: The reason I didn't think it would work initially was because I was doing HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c# objects") which gave me: "http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2fsearch%3fhl%3den%26q%3dc%23+objects". Your edit though showed me how to use it. Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want a dependency on System.Web here is an implementation of "UrlEncode" I have in my C# OAuth Library (which requires a correct implementation - namely spaces should be encoded using percent encoding rather the "+" for spaces etc.)

```
private readonly static string reservedCharacters = "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]";

public static string UrlEncode(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return String.Empty;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char @char in value)
    {
        if (reservedCharacters.IndexOf(@char) == -1)
            sb.Append(@char);
        else
            sb.AppendFormat("%{0:X2}", (int)@char);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

For reference
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Good! Unlike the methods in System.Web this also encodes special characters. (Had to add '-' to the list of reserverd characters)

Comment: What about spaces? They were not encoded to %20 as they should.

Answer (score 12):

@Wilfred Knievel has the accepted answer, but you could also use `Uri.EscapeUriString()` if you wanted to avoid the dependency on the `System.Web` namespace.

Comment: best solution if you are using .net client only.

Comment: This option is great for just encoding special characters like accents and not everything, like slashes or colons.

Answer (score 5):

Look at Server.UrlEncode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738.aspx

Comment: You should be still able to reference the relevant library to perform that encoding operation.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers to this have been deprecated.

In modern C# the solution is to use

```cs
string unescaped = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c# objects"
string escaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(unescaped);
```

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=net-8.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.unescapedatastring?view=net-8.0