# my URL with special parameter doesn't fetch and index in google , I have crawler error

Tags: seo, url-parameters, urlfetch, google-crawlers

my URL with special parameter doesn't fetch and index in google and I have crawler error for all Urls include this parameter '#!'

mysite.com/products/دوربین/1187/view/#!/productgroup-1187/attributes-576644-2207/

and fetching in google just support this:/products/دوربین/1187/view/
mean after the URL that includes '#!' and google fetch doesn't show or know another charter after
/products/دوربین/1187/view/

this parameter used for sorting and filtering 
in google  URL parameter show the parameter as "_escaped_fragment_" I changed same as follows Pic

crawler error URL:mysite.com/products/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C/1145/view/?**_escaped_fragment_=**/productgroup-1145/attributes-100686-2305/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBSIt.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be able to encode those characters using a website like this: http://www.url-encode-decode.com  For example:

```
mysite.com/products/دوربین/1187/view/#!/productgroup-1187/attributes-576644-2207
```

becomes:

```
mysite.com%2Fproducts%2F%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%2F1187%2Fview%2F%23%21%2Fproductgroup-1187%2Fattributes-576644-2207
```

Depending on the language you are using there are library functions that can help you achieve this translation programmatically.

As you are using C#, you could try the UriBuilder class.  Here's some demo code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var oURL = new UriBuilder("mysite.com/products/دوربین/1187/view/#!/productgroup-1187/attributes-576644-2207");
            string sEscapedURL = oURL.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

            Console.WriteLine("sEscapedURL = {0}", sEscapedURL);
            Console.ReadLine(); //Pause
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My language is Persian and google supported it.but in crawler error problem with this parameter that i used in my URL '#!' for sorting & filtering

Comment: Sorry, by "language" I meant programming language. E.g. In C# you can encode special characters in a URL as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533527/how-do-i-replace-special-characters-in-a-url

Comment: thank you for your answer . my programming language is C# , but i found problem about "#!" ajax character in URL that .doesn't support by google and converted to "?_escaped_fragment_=" . I  thinking to use redirect 301. because google doesn't support it.

Comment: I've added to my answer above.  The UriBuilder.AbsoluteUri method might be what you need?